# Handling table format edits

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

After reviewing a few suggested edits today, I saw multiple come through that were only adding table format to a post.  Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4233540) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4233531).

How should these edits be handled?  Unless the formatting of the table was really unacceptable, I have been rejecting these edits as too minor.  Is that the correct way to handle them?  Or is there an argument that the table format significantly improves these posts?

Comment: `Unless the formatting of the table was really unacceptable, I have been rejecting these edits as too minor.` I'd do the same thing, but I guess there is no harm approving them either.

Comment: It's seeing edits like these that make me wonder whether or not me having an accept rate below 50% is a good thing. (I saw a couple of these too and rejected, but both got approved anyway)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a suggested edit is just a cosmetic edit like this:

**Before:**

```
Rank SecurityID  FundID  Value
1        23         A      5
2        43         A      4
3        44         A      3
1        72         B      8
2        75         B      7
3        76         B      2
1        83         C      5
```

**After:**

```
+------+------------+--------+-------+
| Rank | SecurityID | FundID | Value |
+------+------------+--------+-------+
| 1    | 23         | A      | 5     |
| 2    | 43         | A      | 4     |
| 3    | 44         | A      | 3     |
| 1    | 72         | B      | 8     |
| 2    | 75         | B      | 7     |
| 3    | 76         | B      | 2     |
| 1    | 83         | C      | 5     |
+------+------------+--------+-------+
```

**reject** it as *too minor*. Because even without that edit we were able to read the table properly.

But if it actually formats the table (just format it as code) like this:

**Before:**

Rank SecurityID  FundID  Value
1        23         A      5
2        43         A      4
3        44         A      3
1        72         B      8
2        75         B      7
3        76         B      2
1        83         C      5

**After:**

```
Rank SecurityID  FundID  Value
1        23         A      5
2        43         A      4
3        44         A      3
1        72         B      8
2        75         B      7
3        76         B      2
1        83         C      5
```

then **approve** it even it looks a minor edit. Because before the edit I was not able to read the table and mostly new users do this mistake. But if the post needed more edit apart from table format and the suggester didn't do that, I will improve it. (Checking *Suggested edit was helpful* is up to the situation.)

Answer (score 0):

These are mostly superfluous, useless edits.

[Your first example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4233540) is an exception, and only for one reason: it made the table more readable by adding some spacing between the headings. However, this could have been solved by... adding spaces.

The other is just prettifying the table, which is unnecessary - it was already quite readable.